# Can I add a web page as a document to google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to add a 'file' to my drive which is  simply a link to a website/page. I have tried creating a file with alternateLink and webContentLink fields specified but they just get overwritten.

I want to be able to store the link in Drive, retrieve it and use it in my app at a later date.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from creating a document that contains a link, which will open in your app. Your app will read the document content, and do what it wishes with the URL. If you are expecting the Google Drive web application to understand and open the URL, then that won't work. It must be your app that does that.

Comment: Why don't you use Google Sites (http://sites.google.com) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can but not like that. You can:
1) write your own custom file and store the link as file data
2) additionally if you want the link to open from drive you can (unlike a comment in this question that saus you cant) by writting a Drive app and handle the file-open. See https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2500820?hl=en

Comment: Try reading my comment again. Drive will NOT open the link directly, but it can pass the file ID to an app which can then open the file, read the link and open it.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was the 'shortcut' mimetype : "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk", as described in [create_a_shortcut_to_a_file](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-create#create_a_shortcut_to_a_file). When I create a file with that mimeType, the alternateLink does not get overwritten. A 'file' is created in my drive and I can use the alternateLink to navigate to tghe page.